# Confusing derivative problem

Tags: calculus

I'm having a lot of problem with this question. If $f(x) = 3xe^x \cdot g(x)$ and $g(0) = 10$ and $g'(0) = 3$, find $f'(0)$. Can someone please help me

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Product Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule), $\displaystyle f'(x)=3\frac{dx}{dx}e^xg(x)+3xe^x\frac{d \ g(x)}{dx}+3x\frac{d\ e^x}{dx}g(x)$

$\displaystyle\implies f'(x)=3e^xg(x)+3xe^xg'(x)+3xe^xg(x)$

$\displaystyle\implies f'(c)=3[e^cg(c)+c\cdot e^cg'(c)+c\cdot e^cg(c)]=\cdots$

Here $c=0$

Can you identify the usage of $g'(0),$ here?

Comment: so it would read 3[e^c * 10 + 0 * 3 + 0 * e^0 * 10]?

Comment: @user131646, Why don't you set $c=0$ and we don't really need $g'(0)$ as long as it is finite as it is multiplied by $0$

Comment: Here's my correction: 3[e^0 * 10 + 0 * 3 + 0 * e^0 * 10]?

Comment: @user131646, don you have any confusion?

Comment: Am I on the right track or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user131646, have you understood the method described?

Comment: My interpretation of the method can be seen in my response to you.